# Why did Stack Exchange ditch WordPress for their blog?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, blog

I am talking about [this blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com) that Stack Exchange runs.

I am sure previously it used to run on [WordPress](http://www.wordpress.com/). Now why all of sudden was it needed to switch the blog layout and ditch WordPress (don't they use WordPress anymore for their blog)? And if so why did it take so long?

Comment: Have you seen http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/07/the-new-stack-exchange-blog?

Comment: This can be answered by linking to the [blog post](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/07/how-we-built-our-blog/). Why did it take so long? They didn't have dedicated employees to handle outreach, is my guess. Why does it matter even?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - static blogs are more secure...

Comment: @DeerHunter: which is why my blog is also using Jekyll and has been for years. :-)

Comment: "During the original proposal stage for the engineering blog, we also had a conversation about what engine we would use. At the time, all of our blogs were running WordPress...which we weren't so happy about. It was **very buggy**, **difficult to log in to**, **not very performant**, and has caused our SRE team more than a few headaches. If we were really going to revamp the new company blog, it seemed like a lot of work to try and wrestle with our WordPress installation."

Comment: @Dronehinge I don't follow why we should "just close wordpress.SE" just because the SE dev team made a decision to move away from Wordpress. They seem to be much happier with the way they came up with; it seems unlikely whether asking questions on wordpress.SE could have changed the fundamental problems they were having with WP, many of which are inherent to the way it has grown over the years. (Disclaimer: I love and use WP)

Comment: @Pëkka , so We need to modify Tech stack for Stackoverflow Blog here : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network#answer-10370

Comment: The new version of the blog (that also imported all the old blog posts) is based on WordPress. From about 2018/2019(?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should read: [How we built our blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/07/how-we-built-our-blog/)

---

> Why did Stack Exchange ditch WordPress for their blog?
>
> why all of sudden was it needed to switch the blog layout and ditch WordPress?

Because WordPress is not ideal for their requirements.

Sure, WordPress is great in some ways, it's easy to setup, it's flexible as you can bolt-on anything you need - themes and plugins, etc. So for *basic users* wanting to blog it's arguably ok.

But it has limitations and problems, which is not ideal for a company with specific requirements, especially when Stack Exchange has in-house developers.
A lot of the plugins are buggy and some not secure, and any updates and fixes are entirely dependent upon third-party users and companies.

Stack Exchange could (and probably do) write their own plugins for WordPress, but plugins are just "hooks" into the CMS code based on what hooks are provided. And this has various limitations and is not good code really.

So they are no longer bound by *someone else's* architecture. Well, apart from [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), but it's only a small foundation to built your own blog onto. And Wordpress uses procedural functions throughout it's Core, which brings a lot of limitation without arduously re-writing some of the Core - and any self-respecting dev company won't like that :)

They also lose *bloat*, because they only put in what's required, and Wordpress is bloated as it tries to cater for various scenarios out of the box.

As they've made it open source housed on GitHub, you can make [pull-requests](https://github.com/StackExchange/blog/pulls) to add features or make fixes.

---

Stack Exchange using WordPress is like a home removal company using a *small car* to move people's furniture around. 
Using the small car they cannot fit large items in at all; everything is time consuming and requires lots of journeys, and everything is labour intensive.

Stack Exchange using their *own* blog code is like the removal company buying a *large van*. 
The job requirements become much easier, and they can do what they need without the previous limitations.

> And if so why did it take so long?

I don't know how long it took as I'm not sure if "[6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)" is a joke or not. 
But, how long *should* it have taken?